# How to export data with functions to another workbook in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Please refer the attached picture. I need to copy data in column "Total Qty" to another workbook and save it in to a specific folder by giving the file name as Shipment ID. In this I recall that file and get data from it to a another column.

[image]

I need to add something more to this, i.e. I want to check whether the file is there or not in the specific folder. If the file exists, need to update the file. If the file doesn't exist, create a file using the column "Total Qty".

I have written the below code for this. It worked until I give a function to the column "total qty" as "=(G2+H2)". After giving the function, destination file shows as "=(#REF!+#REF!)" in cells.

```
Sub Export_Total_Qty()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim ID As String, abc

    Const FILE_INFO As String = "D:\Excel Software\Shipment Tracking\Junk\<id>.xlsx"

    ID = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "O").Value

    abc = Replace(FILE_INFO, "<id>", ID)

    FilePath = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    FilePath = Dir(abc)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FilePath = "" Then


         Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I50").Copy
         Workbooks.Add
         ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=abc

         MsgBox "New Entry is created, Thak you", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G50").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")
        'ActiveWorkbook.Update _
        Filename:=abc
        MsgBox "successfully Updated", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Sub
```

Comment: If you copy a formula into column A which refers to the two columns to the left of it, it will naturally complain.  Did you just want to copy the values instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your reference turns sour when you exit the environment where those formulas are pointing to (columns in your source worksheet becoming bad reference). You could try to use the Paste Special function, which will allow you to specify that you only wish to copy the values.
To do that change `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")` to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteValues`

Maybe [the docs for PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) will help you.

I would also advise you not to use `ActiveWorksheet`/`ActiveWorksheet` and rather introduce new object variables of type `Worksheet`/`Workbook` as I have made the experience that they are simply more robust.